# How to send an ajax form with a file using FormData / Java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, form-data

I'm trying to send a post to the server but I'm getting always an error **415** I have tried multiples things but nothing.

js:

```
var form = $('form')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "./signup",
       data: formData,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success : function(data) {
           //...
       },
       error : function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           console.log(errorThrown, "Error " + qXHR.status);
       }
    });
```

html:

```
<form id="signup-form" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" type="text" id="firstName">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Surname</label>
    <input name="surname" type="text" id="surname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>File</label>
    <input type="file" name="attachFile" id="attachFile">
   </div>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" id="btn-submit-signup value="Submit">
</form>
```

java

```
//controller header
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Response<String> signup(@RequestBody UserSignup details) 



//UserSignup
public class UserSignup {
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private MultipartFile attachFile;

    public UserSignup(){}

    //getters and setters...
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: can you check in the browser if the request is sent to server properly?

Comment: Well, I'm getting an error 415. Before was working perfectly because I was sending a json with this call and now I need to send a file so I have changed the code to do this with the FormData. @SpringLearner

Comment: well you can have another method parameter @RequestParam MultipartFile file and provide a datatype in your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a guide on how to properly handle file uploads: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Taken from the guide, here is a quick example

Controller

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        storageService.store(file);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Form

```
<form id="signup-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
    <table>
        <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Ajax

```
$.post("./signup", $("#signup-form").serialize());
```